# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ converge.

---

According to Wolfram Alpha, the sum converges to a value $-2.239...$

**Problem**::
But isn't it true that the limit of the absolute value of the terms is $e$ and not zero? I thought this means it cannot converge.

Thanks.

Comment: You are right. The series does not converge.

Comment: But how can I go against all know wolfram alpha?https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5En%281%2B1%2Fn%29%5E%28n%2B1%29+sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: For what it's worth, WolframAlpha (i) is not the truth, and makes mistakes/interprets the input in sometimes unexpected ways; (ii) in this particular case, does *sometimes* return "sum does not converge" in my case. (roughly every other time I click on the link.)

Comment: Also: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convergence+of+series+%28-1%29%5En%281%2B1%2Fn%29%5E%28n%2B1%29+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$(a_n)=\sum_{m=1}^n (-1)^m\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m+1}$$

As pointed out by Kabo Murphy, the series does diverge, that is $(a_n)$ diverges. The reason Wolfram alpha said $(a_n)\to -2.239...$ is because $(a_n)$ has two convergent subsequences: $(a_{2n})\to -0.880...$ and $(a_{2n+1})\to -3.599...$. Taking the average of the two, $(a_n)\to-2.239...$ which is how Wolfram Alpha probably got the solution.

Comment: May I ask why $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n + 1})$ converge?

Comment: @Azlif $$(a_{2n})=\sum_{m=1}^n \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2m}\right)^{2m+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{2m-1}\right)^{2m}\right)$$

$$(a_{2n+1})=-\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{\left(2n+1\right)}+(a_{2n})$$

You can use the ratio test to show that $(a_{2n})$ converges (then $(a_{2n+1})$ converges as well). $(a_{2n})$ was obtained by writing out the sum term by term and grouping every two terms together.